# Python Pandas Building full matrix of contrasts

Tags: python, loops, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a specific query using Python Pandas.
Apologies for the poor presentation

I have a df like that

```
CG | T
------


    10   | 0.5   
    21   | 0.2  
    33   | 0.3  
    45   | 0.6
```

I would like to build all the contrasts possibles for CG
That would be something like

```
CG1 || CG2 || T1 || T2 || contrast||   
10 || 21 || 0.5 || 0.2 || 0.3 ||   
10 || 33 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.2 ||   
10 || 45 || 0.5 || 0.6 || -0.1 ||   
21 || 33 || 0.2 || 0.3 || -0.1 ||     
21 || 45|| 0.2 || 0.6  || -0.4 ||   
33 || 45 || 0.3 || 0.6 || -0.3 ||
```

I have a loop done that loops through all the rows and merges back - not very efficient when the data become big (n CG = 800)
I was wondering if 1) there was an efficient way of doing such a loop or/and 2) transforming the df into a matrix of contracts like this :

```
--- || 10 || 21 || 33 || 45 ||  
10 || 0.5 || 0.3 || 0.2 || -0.1 ||    
21 || 0.3 || 0.2 || -0.1 || -0.4 ||  
33 || 0.2 || -0.1 || 0.3 || -0.3 ||   
45|| -0.1 || -0.4 ||-0.3 || 0.6 ||
```

I have read several posts on looping efficiently - the specificity of this query is the fact that I want to build contrasts between all the groups (CG) ; it's like strating with a diagonal matrix and wanting to fill all the off-diagonal cells with differences taken from the diagonal elements (hence my idea of using matrices).

Cheers all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a NumPy way using initializing and assigning in steps -

```
n = a.shape[0]
r,c = np.triu_indices(n,1)
L = len(r)
out = np.empty((L,5))
out[:,:-1:2] = a[r]
out[:,1::2] = a[c]
out[:,-1] = out[:,2] - out[:,3]
```

Sample input, output -

```
In [105]: a
Out[105]: 
array([[ 10. ,   0.5],
       [ 21. ,   0.2],
       [ 33. ,   0.3],
       [ 45. ,   0.6]])

In [106]: out
Out[106]: 
array([[ 10. ,  21. ,   0.5,   0.2,   0.3],
       [ 10. ,  33. ,   0.5,   0.3,   0.2],
       [ 10. ,  45. ,   0.5,   0.6,  -0.1],
       [ 21. ,  33. ,   0.2,   0.3,  -0.1],
       [ 21. ,  45. ,   0.2,   0.6,  -0.4],
       [ 33. ,  45. ,   0.3,   0.6,  -0.3]])
```

Only work to interface with `pandas` dataframe is getting input array `a` with `a = df.values`, where `df` is the input dataframe and then using the proposed method. Finally, the output could be converted to a dataframe with a call to `pd.Dataframe(out)` to get the output dataframe.

Comment: excellent stuff Divakar - I'm gonna put that to the test! Many thanks!

Comment: @MrT. Would love some speedup numbers from your actual dataset, if possible.

Comment: running now! very efficient piece of code - guesstimate gain of time ~ +50%. Many thanks Divakar. Cheers